# How to make laravel API localization structure

Tags: laravel, api, oop, localization, structure

I'm using [laravel-translatable](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-translatable/v6/introduction/).
I want to make something dynamic with the return in all Resources,
So when I receive Params like **lang=fr** it dynamically returns the **fr** translation.
But I want a way to do it in one place, not in every "*Model* - *Controller* - *Resource*".

I was thinking of making a class that will handle the logic and then implements it in every controller.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If you want code that runs for every API route then create a middleware with that code and put that middleware in the API group in your `App\Http\Kernel`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.